# What does cmdclass do in Pythons setuptools?

Tags: python, setuptools

I've recently got a pull request which added

```
class build_ext(_build_ext):
    'to install numpy'
    def finalize_options(self):
        _build_ext.finalize_options(self)
        # Prevent numpy from thinking it is still in its setup process:
        __builtins__.__NUMPY_SETUP__ = False
        import numpy
        self.include_dirs.append(numpy.get_include())
```

to my `setup.py` resulting in:

```
from setuptools.command.build_ext import build_ext as _build_ext

try:
    from setuptools import setup
except ImportError:
    from distutils.core import setup


class build_ext(_build_ext):
    'to install numpy'
    def finalize_options(self):
        _build_ext.finalize_options(self)
        # Prevent numpy from thinking it is still in its setup process:
        __builtins__.__NUMPY_SETUP__ = False
        import numpy
        self.include_dirs.append(numpy.get_include())


config = {
    'cmdclass':{'build_ext':build_ext}, #numpy hack
    'setup_requires':['numpy'],         #numpy hack
    'name': 'nntoolkit',
    'version': '0.1.25',
    'author': 'Martin Thoma',
    'author_email': 'info@martin-thoma.de',
    'packages': ['nntoolkit'],
    'scripts': ['bin/nntoolkit'],
    'url': 'https://github.com/MartinThoma/nntoolkit',
    'license': 'MIT',
    'description': 'Neural Network Toolkit',
    'long_description': """...""",
    'install_requires': [
        "argparse",
        "theano",
        "nose",
        "natsort",
        "PyYAML",
        "matplotlib",
        "h5py",
        "numpy",
        "Cython"
    ],
    'keywords': ['Neural Networks', 'Feed-Forward', 'NN', 'MLP'],
    'download_url': 'https://github.com/MartinThoma/nntoolkit',
    'classifiers': ['Development Status :: 3 - Alpha'],
    'zip_safe': False,
    'test_suite': 'nose.collector'
}

setup(**config)
```

What does it do?

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/apiref.html) only states:

> cmdclass: A mapping of command names to [**`Command`**](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/apiref.html?highlight=cmdclass#distutils.core.Command) subclasses (a dictionary)

Comment: There is obviously a typo. It should be: 'cmdclass':{'build_ext':build_ext}, #numpy hack

Answer (score 8):

Numpy libraries are written in C/C++. So unlike other packages, it needs to be compiled before actually calling them. So 'build_ext' just compiles them.

Details in blog: http://sadafnoor.me/blog/how-to-automate-numpy-installation-in-your-project-using-setuptool/

Comment: I didn't know you had a blog. Congratulations, you've got a new subscriber :-)

What I don't understand is how this code finds the C/C++ source code. Does it work on all systems (it seems to work on Linux Mint. How about other distros? Does it work on Windows?)

Comment: Now the page is gone.

Comment: @TomaszGandor this is the updated (?) link http://blog.sadafnoor.me/blog/how-to-automate-numpy-installation-in-your-project-using-setuptool/

Comment: which is also not working anymore :-) but more info to be found here https://realitix.github.io/python/2016/11/09/python-customize-setup/

Answer (score 3):

All con:

I found this other blog that explained it very well:

https://niteo.co/blog/setuptools-run-custom-code-in-setup-py

Shout-out to studioj as well; that page explains the same thing, but for distutils instead of setuptools (which are VERY similar in their apparent definition).

Essentially, these are creating classes to override various commands used by setuptools/distutils (particularly their ".run" commands).

For example, if you wanted to override the "build" command in setuptools, you could use a pattern like so:

```
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.command.build import build

class MyBuild(build):
    def run(self):
        # ---- some custom code here ----
        # important to do this instead of "super", since it hasn't been properly updated
        build.run(self) 

setup(
    # setup specifications here
    cmdclass={"build": MyBuild}
)
```